# Magento Custom Module - WYSIWYG image browse issue

Tags: wysiwyg, magento

I have a custom module with a content field (WYSIWYG editor)

When I select the insert image button, the following popup appears. For some reason the 'browse' button at the side of the Image URL has disappeared. Can someone point me in the right direction to get the image icon back? (what block/controller etc)

What is required when adding the full featured WYSIWYG editor to a custom magento module?

[image: No browse icon at side of image url]

This is my form field element within Form.php (block)

```
$fieldset->addField('post_content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'post_content',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
    'wysiwyg'   => true,
));
```

Thank you.

Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to sort this by adding some configuration options to the field,

Add the following code above the addField() of your WYSIWYG,

```
$configSettings = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig( 
array( 'add_widgets' => false, 'add_variables' => false, 'add_images' => false,  'files_browser_window_url'=> $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/'));
```

Once you've added the code, you need to add another param to the addField called 'config' calling your $configSettings variable.

```
$fieldset->addField('post_content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'post_content',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('faqs')->__('Answer'),
    'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
    'wysiwyg'   => true,
    'config' => $configSettings
));
```

Answer (score 5):

Had to find out the hard way, but the solution is quite simple:

Please **check the permissions of your Role** your Admin is in unser **System=>Permissions=>Roles**

There you can find in the Tab "**Role Resources**" the Checkbox "**Media Gallery**". Make sure this checkbox is ticked!

Then, clean cache, log out and in again and it should work.

Cheers!